# Orthogonal Projection of y on range (x)

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working on a problem set for econometrics, I wanted to verify that I correctly understand what I'm doing…

Given $x=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$, find the orthogonal projection of $y$ on range($x$).

I think I understand that the orthogonal projection on range($x$) is given by $PX=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ where $X'$ is the transpose of $X$. For the orthogonal projection of $y$ on range($x$) I noted that $P_xY =X(W'X)^{-1}W'$ - but I have no clue why…?

Would greatly appreciate, if someone could

a) confirm that $P_xY =X(W'X)^{-1}W'$ is the correct approach?
b) and what this means?

Many, many thanks, best,

Matthias

Comment: Perhaps this video helps. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/orthogonal_projections/v/linear-algebra--projections-onto-subspaces

Comment: many thanks :) i'll look into these videos.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular question the answer is just
$$\frac{\langle y,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}x=\frac{y'x}{x'x}x.$$

Michael